# SuiteScript N/query SuiteQL how to select one transaction like Estimate

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I try some demo SuiteQL in NetSuite by following the demo that the SuiteScript 2.0API provides, but the demo seemed too little for me, I still cannot figure out the right way to use it properly, and I had to come back to module N/search.

so I wanna ask for some demo about SuiteQL, especially for Transaction.
Thank you!

Comment: Is there something you are specifically trying to accomplish? Have you looked through the SuiteScript 2.0 API Reference so see what all is available? https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSAPI/NSAPI.pdf

Comment: By relook in the doc page 501, I think I've got some hint,
demo code is bellow

require(['N/query']);
const query = require('N/query');
var suiteQL = "select tranid from Transaction where Transaction.status in 'Estimate:X'";
var resultSuiteQL = query.runSuiteQL(suiteQL);

by This SQL, I can get the Estimate data I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you could use the query module to achieve your goal. In this example you would pass whatever type of transaction you wanted to query by using the function `queryTransactionsFilteredByStatus` defined below and pass to it whatever status you would like. This could obviously be expanded on to fit your use case more specifically.

```js
define(['N/query'], (query) => {
  const queryTransactionsFilteredByStatus = (status) => {
    const sql = `select * from transaction as t where t.status = ?`;
    return query.runSuiteQL({
      query: sql,
      params: [status]
    }).asMappedResults();
  }
  
  // The rest of your code here...
}
```